# Removing duplicates from List of object

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, duplicates

I am new to Type script and trying to remove duplicate objects based on property in my case its only id. I am trying to use filter but unable to do so. I have pasted my code below . Could any one please guide me. 
MY list is of type employee and i have created model class for employee.id can be duplicate because of some bad data and as work around i need to remove duplicate from list and show it to the UI.

I have tried to convert it to set but didn't work.

```
     ids : Employee[] = new Array<Employee>();
     this.list.filter((this.list=> ids.includes(this.list.idPk) ? false : ids.push(this.list.idPk));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ids : Employee[] = new Array<Employee>();

 var newList  = this.list.filter(list => !ids.includes(list.idPk));
 ids.concat(newList)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back to you as I was overloaded with current project work and put my learning at a side. Thank you for your answer i tried to do it but it gives me exception for semicolons even though i have put all semicolons. this list can have duplciate products having the same id.  private productsList: Product[] = new Array<Product>();
   private prdList: Product[] = new Array<Product>();

   this.prdList  = this.productsList.filter(
    productsList => !this.prdList.includes(productsList.rowidObject));
   this.productsList = this.prdList;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't get back to you as I was overloaded with current project work and put my learning at a side. Thank you for your answer i tried to do it but it gives me exception for semicolons even though i have put all semicolons. this list can have duplciate products having the same id. I need to remove duplicates based on Id from product.

```
   private productsList: Product[] = new Array<Product>();
   private prdList: Product[] = new Array<Product>();

   this.prdList  = this.productsList.filter(
    productsList => !this.prdList.includes(productsList.rowidObject));
   this.productsList = this.prdList;
```